# How to deal with incrementing and decrementing ko.observables floating point

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have prepared a small jsfiddle here: jsfiddle.net/v8s176p2

Basically I want to increment and decrement observable in steps of 0.1 But because of number representation and precision issues, numbers are sometimes displayed as:1.3200000000000003...etc, tu I want them to only be displayed and have values with 1 decimal point

How would I code this exact same functionality in knockout.js, but by not using floating point. So my starting value is 10 and in HTML it's displayed as 1, if I decrmenet it (10-1 = 9) in html it's displayed as 0.9? This is probably better approach for my application, since I get this data from a server on embedded device, so it would be better to recieve the number as 200 and then divide it by 10, but how to set this up in ko.js in my example fiddle?

Comment: why do you choose knockout instead angular2+, react or vue ?

Comment: It's legacy code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Work with integers and do division in the text binding to display the floating point. This keeps the backing data as ints so errors won't accumulate.

```html
data-bind="text: num1() / 10"
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xagup8vt/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom binding, something like this

```
ko.bindingHandlers.numericText = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor) {
        var value = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
        var formattedValue = value.toFixed(2);
        ko.bindingHandlers.text.update(element, function () { return formattedValue; });
    }
};
```

There you can format the value however you like, and then use it like this:

```
<p data-bind="numericText: num1"></p>
```

Comment: Isn't there a more elegant way? Why can't it remain 
    <p data-bind="text: num1"></p>
And then implement logic on model side to represent it with only one decimal place

Comment: I tried this here: http://jsfiddle.net/tj54ukx0/1/
And it seems it works. But does my num1 now contain formmated value or it's true value?

Also, How to do this without using floating point, but rather, whole numbers, and them divide by 10 to represent them as floating points?

Comment: @johndoe it is the true value, as for elegance, personally I think that the custom bindings is one of the few points of elegance in knockout. As for dividing by 10, you have to replace the conversion of value.toFixed with value/10

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to to add a computed observable to the observable property like

```
var vm = function(){
    var self = this;
    self.num1 = ko.observable();
    self.num1.formatted = ko.computed(function(){ return  Math.round((self.num1()*10),0)/10; });
}
```

This way the formatting is contained with the view model and converting the `vm` object to JSON will ignore the formatted computed function in the output.

To use it,
`<p data-bind="text: num1.formatted"></p>`

Another option is to use a writable computed observable.
I have included both techniques in the following snippet.

```js
var increment = function(observable) {
  observable(observable() + 0.1);
};
var decrement = function(observable) {
  observable(observable() - 0.1);
};

var MyViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.num1 = ko.observable(0);
  self.num1.formatted = ko.computed(function() {
    return Math.round((self.num1() * 10), 0) / 10;
  });
  var num2BackingProperty = ko.observable(0);
  self.num2 = ko.computed({

    read: function() {
      return num2BackingProperty();
    },
    write: function(value) {
      num2BackingProperty(Math.round((value * 10), 0) / 10);
    },
    owner: self
  })

  this.incrementNum = function(observable) {
    // passing the observable by reference to the helper function
    increment(observable);
  };

  this.decrementNum = function(observable) {
    decrement(observable);
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

```css
h3 {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button data-bind="click: incrementNum.bind($root, num1)">Increment Num1</button>
<button data-bind="click: decrementNum.bind($root, num1)">Decrement Num1</button>
<h3>
  Formatted
</h3>
<p data-bind="text: num1.formatted"></p>
<h3>
  Unformatted
</h3>
<p data-bind="text: num1"></p>
<br/>
<br/>
<button data-bind="click: incrementNum.bind($root, num2)">Increment Num2</button>
<button data-bind="click: decrementNum.bind($root, num2)">Decrement Num2</button>

<h3>
  Writable Computed
</h3>
<p data-bind="text: num2"></p>
<br/>
<h3>
  View Model Json
</h3>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></pre>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gonefishern/yo2nurf8/30/

Comment: thank you for such a detailed answer. It is almost excatly what I wanted. Just a small detail, to be complete..How to format it and code it so that our original num1 or num2 are only whole numbers (e.g. 100), and only in view model are they display as 100/10 = 10 or 101/10 =10.1 with only one decimal place